# Insert data to table3 depending on matches in table1 and dissmatches in table2

Tags: sql, oracle

Want to make simple Lost and Found database. I have table2 (Add in system) where "costumer" come in and define "ztracena_/_nalezea" by 0 for lost and 1 for found.
Then he more specifies that thing in table1 like weight, color etc...
Now I want to fill table3 (match) with data from these two. I need to have match in table2 but also I need these thing to be one lost 0 and one found 1 (table2).
Really hope I explain it simply enough. Thanks for help! [image]

Comment: Post sample data, your effort and expected output

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you can provide sample data and desired results. I think this does what you want:

```
with t1 as (
  select 1 as flag, 1 as id from dual union all
  select 1 as flag, 2 as id from dual union all
  select 0 as flag, 3 as id from dual union all
  select 0 as flag, 4 as id from dual
), t2 as (
  select 1 as id, 'yellow' as color, 'hat' as category from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 'red' as color, 'box' as category from dual union all
  select 3 as id, 'yellow' as color, 'hat' as category from dual union all
  select 4 as id, 'red' as color, 'hat' as category from dual
)
select tflag0.id || ' matches ' || tflag1.id from 
  (select t1.id, t2.color, t2.category from t1  inner join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) where flag = 0) tflag0 --things lost
  inner join 
  (select t1.id, t2.color, t2.category from t1  inner join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) where flag = 1) tflag1 --things found
  on (tflag0.color = tflag1.color and tflag0.category = tflag1.category);
```

First part defines `t1` as your table where we put something that means found/lost in `t2` we have description on things. Query gives us `id`s from `t1` that have same descriptions and one person found it and another lost it. Now please try to adapt the solution to your model.

Comment: So here is my problem explained in picture [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/a6ff75aaf7.jpg)  or alternative [link](http://imgur.com/a/ej2yR)   Thanks for help!!!

Comment: + Iam sorry in that picture in mistake at table1 3rd and 4th are not matching different color didnt realise it... Was testing something and didnt put it back... but 1st and 2nd are still in match... so pleas look at those :)